# How to save a whole website as a jpg or png in order to post it on Behance?

Tags: web, png, jpeg, presentation

I am finally done with my website and now I am looking for the best and easiest way to save it as .jpg or .png in order to be able to present it on Behance. What is the best way to do this?

I used HTML, CSS and JQuery to build my single page website.

I kindly ask you to help me with this as I am still new to coding and am still discovering the world of web design!

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several addons that you can use to screen capture an entire webpage. Webpage Screenshot is one that works in Firefox and Chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-screenshot/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki?hl=en

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/

Comment: Thanks! I will try this addon. I wanted to vote up for your answer but I got the message that I need to have my reputation 15 points.

Comment: Should be able to now :)

Comment: Great! Now it says I have to wait for another 4 minutes to accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it correctly, you want to save your webpage as an image to display it as a presentation.

There are many options you have.

One of them is to take a screenshot of the webpage and use a GFX editing program to crop it to your liking and save it.

Another of them is to use a browser add-ons to take a screenshot of the web page and save it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My page has a height of 4000 pixels. How do I take such a long screenshot? Thanks again :)

Comment: You can try Chrome's extension for Webpage Screenshot which is really nice. I never personally had to do it so I can't recommend anything but if I were to do it. I would do page at a time and then use a GFX app to add them together.